# new environment conda install pandas

Tags: python, conda

If I create a new environment in conda and add packages, shouldn't the python interpreter still find packages in the base installation if I don't add them to the new environment?  For example:

```
conda create -n work pysal
```

then activate and I can't import pandas which is in the base? environment.  Should I be cloning the original install environment and then adding packages, I thought this was the advantage of using environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
conda create -n <name> <packages>
```

creates a new environment containing only those packages that are explicitly given to the create command.
Using the install command you can install pandas in your new environment. If the package in your base environment or any other environment is already there it won't be downloaded again (only linked) if the following conditions are true:

- the python in both environments versions match
- the package is up to date

The advantage of having environments is that packages are **not** shared across them.